# Mapping FTL items to html items

Tags: javascript, html, struts2, freemarker

I have a Java EE application where I use a ftl template to generate a data grid. below is the grid template.

```
  <tr id="_gridRow_3345${item.id}"" onclick="gridRowClick(${item.id?c},this); return true;">
            <td ${cssStyle} align="left" valign="middle" width="5%" style ="overflow: hidden;" >                
                <font> ${rowCount?c} </font>            
            </td>
            <td ${cssStyle} align="left" valign="middle" width="40%" style ="overflow: hidden;" >               
                <font> ${item.hotelName!"&nbsp;"} </font>           
            </td>
            <td ${cssStyle} align="left" valign="middle" width="40%" style ="overflow: hidden;" >               
                <font> ${item.taxCode!"&nbsp;"} </font>         
            </td>
            <td ${cssStyle} align="left" valign="middle" width="10%" style ="overflow: hidden;" >               
                <font> ${item.dispSeq!"&nbsp;"} </font>         
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Now what I want is to do is when a user clicks on a item row, the row should be mapped on to a set of HTML form items. such as list boxes and text boxes. I wrote a onGridClick method in my JS file and I have an idea for this! I'm parsing the row object. Below is the code.

```
 setField("hotelName", gridObj.id);
```

But the values are not mapped. Is there any other way to achieve this. I'm on a framework of Struts. please help! thank you!

Comment: The `font` element has been deprecated long ago... What does `setField` look like?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve?